# HTTP Proxy with encrypted authentication

Tags: tls, web-browser, proxy

I'm looking for a fast and lightweight HTTPS proxy that supports **encrypted authentication**.

I found a lot of different HTTP proxies e.g. squid, tinyproxy, 3proxy and so on.  Unfortunately none of them seems to support encrypted authentication.

Than I found Stunnel and wanted to connect it with 3proxy. Unfortunately that didn't work.

The thing is that I want the proxy only server side. No additional client side software next to the browser needed. I think its terrible that in the 21st century most of the proxies still use plain text authentication.

So does anyone know to use a HTTPS proxy with Mozilla Firefox with no additional software on the client side?

Comment: Squid supports [digest authentication](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/156334/171/)

Comment: "unfortunately that didn't work" - I can't imagine anything other than an error on your part would cause that.

Comment: digest authentication is just useful to protect the password itself, it does not preventing a sniffer from using the the proxy through the sniffed hashed password

Answer (score 1):

What you wish to accomplish does seam to be possible (but on the edge of it) using squid. Squid is actually capable of intersecting https traffic and it appears the connection to it can be encrypted using command line options. Details are available  [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160325234032/http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#Encrypted_browser-Squid_connection) (at the bottom). You should also note that while no other software will be required client side, you will need to trust squids ca certificate. This is fundamental to the security of https without it anyone could monitor your traffic.